# Determine whether the graph exists or why such a graph does not exist

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am working on the following problem, the text really doesn't say much on questions 2 or 3.  I assume that my answers for 1 and 4 are correct.

For each of the following characteristics, determine whether the graph exists or why such a graph does not exist.

1.simple graph with seven nodes, each of degree 3.

I put does not exist because of the handshake Theorem

2.four nodes, two of degree 2 and two of degree 3.

Exists, but I am not quite sure why

3.three nodes of degree 0, 1, and 3, respectively.

Exists, still not really sure why.

4.complete graph with four nodes each of degree 2.

Does not exist, because a complete graph would have four nodes with a degree of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2, you can show that such a graph exists by drawing one example which satisfies those properties. That's all that you need to do to show that it exists.

> If you are having trouble drawing one, start with a complete graph on 4 nodes and erase one edge.

For 3, recheck your thinking. If there are 3 nodes, can any node be connected to three other nodes?

Comment: There are no rules for question 3 unlike 1 and 4.  So I assume any node can be connected to the three other nodes.